# Write json data to local JSON file using only angular 7

Tags: json, typescript, angular7, angular7-router, angular-json

I have a form on submit of the form I am receiving the json object after form submit. What I am trying is that I have a file data.json in my application folder in "/src/app/data.json". How can I write the data into the JSON file with Node.

Below is my code

Below is the code in my component.ts

```
 savedatatojson(jsonobject){
   // jsonobject is the json data
   this.dataservice.savedata(jsonobject).subscribe(data => {
     console.log(this.data)
  })
 }
```

Below is  the code in my service file

```
 public savedata(jsonobject):Observable<any>{
   //code to be written
 }
```

How do I save data to json file which I have obtained in my service file

Comment: What does "local JSON file" mean? Do you want to save a file on the *server* where the application is deployed, or on the machine of the user using your application? Note that neither the server nor the client will have an `src/app/` folder. This folder only exists on your machine.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, that exists only in my machine and how to save in my machine

Comment: You can't. A user of the application will use its own machine to browse the web, and the application will be deployed on a server, not on your machine. S your machine is ompletely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, web browsers don't have permissions to write to source files. There does exist a [file system api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), however this is non-standard and can only access a very limited location of files.

Instead you should either send the data to a database which later you can read and write to a file, or generate a file within the application which users could download for themselves to their own computer downloads folder. There is also the option to use serverless functions to update a remote file on a server, or for example a google sheet.